# Use PasswordHasher without implementing Asp.Net Identity framework

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

Working on a simple claims based identity and authentication system for web api that doesn't rely on the entire Asp.Net Identity framework.  Is there a way to use `PasswordHasher.HashPassword` and `PasswordHasher.VerifyPassword` as helper methods for hashing and verifying passwords?  If not, is there anything in the .NET Framework that provides this functionality so that one (who is not an expert security programmer) doesn't need to write algorithms for password hashing and parsing?

Comment: No there isn't but writing a hashing algorithm is old hat by now and there are thousands of examples (many on this site) about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the alternative I was looking for:  [System.Web.Helpers.Crypto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.crypto.aspx) contains everything I need including `HashPassword` and `VerifyHashedPassword`.

Answer (score 0):

Just take the [decompiled code](https://gist.github.com/trailmax/553ea84d4d0e2e20fcd7) from Identity and add it to your project.